# Player Chat event in minecraft java plugin doesnt do what its suposed to do

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

So I have coded the following code:

```
package com.ste999.firstplugin;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.event.player.AsyncPlayerChatEvent;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

    public Main() {}

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getLogger().info("Stefan's first plugin enabled");
    }

        private volatile boolean chatEnabled = true;

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerChat(AsyncPlayerChatEvent event) {
        Player pli = event.getPlayer();
        if (!chatEnabled) {
            if (!pli.hasPermission("ste.chat.bypass")) {
                pli.sendMessage("§4Chat is disabled!");
                event.setCancelled(true);
                //return true;
            }
        }
    }

        @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) 
    {
        Player p = (Player)sender;

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("mutechat")) {
            chatEnabled = !chatEnabled;
            sender.sendMessage(chatEnabled ? "§aUnmuted the chat" : "§aMuted the chat");
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        getLogger().info("Stefan's first plugin disabled");
    }
}
```

with the following plugin.yml:

```
name: Stefans_Helper
main: com.ste999.firstplugin.Main
version: 1.0
load: startup
description: this is my first plugin
commands:
  mutechat:
    description: mute the chat
    usage: /<command>
```

When I use this plugin in my Minecraft server, it shows up and if I do `/mutechat` it says `Muted the chat` en when I do `/mutechat` again it says `Unmuted the chat`

What I expect this code to do is when the chat is "Muted" no users can talk, unless they have the `ste.chat.bypass` permission node.

But a user without op and the `ste.chat.bypass` can still talk in chat after someone did `/mutechat` and the chat said `Muted the chat`.

I've tried putting `getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);` in the `public void onEnable` but then I get an error in eclipse that says: `The method registerEvents(Listener, Plugin) in the type PluginManager is not applicable for the arguments (Main, Main)`

Uhh help pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to get the mutechat function with the following code:
package com.ste999.events;

```
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
//import org.bukkit.event.EventPriority;
import org.bukkit.event.player.AsyncPlayerChatEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginManager;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener{
    public static boolean chatMuted = false;
    @Override
    public void onEnable()
    {
        getLogger().info("events tester enabled!");
        PluginManager pm = this.getServer().getPluginManager();
        pm.registerEvents(this, (this));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable()
    {
        getLogger().info("events tester disabled!");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args)
    {
        Player player = (Player)sender;
        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("mutechat")) {
            if (player.hasPermission("ste999.chat.mute")) {
            if(chatMuted == false) {
                Bukkit.broadcastMessage("§aThe chat has been disabled!");
                chatMuted = true;
                }
                else {
                if(chatMuted == true) {
                Bukkit.broadcastMessage("§aThe chat has been enabled!");
                chatMuted = false;
                }
                }
            } else {
                if (!player.hasPermission("ste999.chat.mute")) {
                player.sendMessage("§4You can't mute the chat silly!");
                }
            }
            }
    return false;
    }
    @EventHandler
    public void OnChat(AsyncPlayerChatEvent event)
    {
        Player pli = event.getPlayer();
        if (chatMuted == true) {
            if (!pli.hasPermission("ste999.chat.bypass")) {
                event.setCancelled(true);
                pli.sendMessage("§4The chat has been disabled");
            } else {
                if (pli.hasPermission("ste999.chat.bypass")) {
                    event.setCancelled(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I needed to register the events but `getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this)` didn't work for me so I needed to do it the way I did it in the code in `onEnable` and there where a few other problems

Comment: This is literally what I told you to do. Mega facepalm.

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart You just gave me a link that didn't explain it in detail. Mega mega facepalm

Comment: Quote: "Your events class (I seriously recommend a new class for this) needs to implement the [Listener interface](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/bbcode.1415/archive). Only then can you register it."

If you ignore the link, the information is there.

Anyways, glad you found the answer, happy coding!

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart Like I said. The like you provided gave me the listener class. I didn't know how to use this with my main class. Because if I would've used 2 classes, I needed to know how to setup the main class. But thanks your awnser like I said did help me because I did more research on the things that link provided me.

Answer (score 1):

Your events class (I seriously recommend a new class for this) needs to implement the [Listener interface](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/bbcode.1415/archive). Only then can you register it.

Comment: Hi, I saw how to make the listener but as I'm fairly new to java, could you post the whole code and explain things? thanks!

Comment: @kaci add `implements Listener` to your class declaration and put `getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);` in your `onEnable()`

Comment: Didn't you read my question? I said that I tried `getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);` but it gave an error, Please read my question.

Comment: @kacl please read my answer. If you implement Listener you can register the event

Comment: I already found an awnser but thanks anyways. the link you gave was a big help